# IEqualityComparer GetHashCode

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create a `Distinct` class for a LINQ query. Let's say the Department DTO class looks like this:

```
public class Department
{
    public int ID {get; set;} //primary key
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
}
```

and I need to query by distinct department **names** (not IDs).
Will my `GetHashCode` look like

```
public int GetHashCode(Department record)
{
    return record.NAME.GetHashCode();
}
```

or will it look like

```
public int GetHashCode(Department record)
{
    return record.ID.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: @T.Rahgooy no, it's not

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Comment: If you are going by distinct names why do you think you need `ID` involved at all? Also are you performing this distinct on a `IQueryable<Department>` or a `IEnumerable<Department>`? If you are working with queryables (Like you are using Entity Framework or similar) you can't use IEqualityComparer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well, I'm not sure whether I should use ID or not because I don't know how `GetHashCode` will be used. I've used similar Distincts with EF and it has been working fine. This one was a `IQueryable<Department>`

Comment: Neither should be used as hash codes should not be computed from mutable properties.